# Ruby hash with key as hash and value as array

Tags: ruby, hash

I am creating a hash, whose key is a hash and the value is an array. E.g.,

```
shop = Hash.new
items.each do |item|
  grouping_key = {
    'name'=> item['name'],
    'value'=> item['value']
  }
  shop [grouping_key] ||= Array.new
  shop [grouping_key] << item
end
```

Here, I am grouping each item based on grouping key. For the following items:

```
Item1 = {'name'=>'test', 'value'=>10, 'color'=>'black', 'description'=>'item1'}
Item2 = {'name'=>'test2', 'value'=>10, 'color'=>'blue', 'description'=>'item2'}
Item3 = {'name'=>'test', 'value'=>10, 'color'=>'black', 'description'=>'item3'}
Item4 = {'name'=>'test2', 'value'=>10, 'color'=>'blue', 'description'=>'item4'}
```

my shop hash will be:

```
shop = {{'name'=>'test', 'value'=>10}=>[Item1, Item3], {name=>test2, value=>10}=>[Item2, Item4]}
```

I wanted to add color to hash key, but not as part of grouping key. Is it possible to do so without reiterating over hash and modifying it? e.g.

```
shop = {{'name'=>'test', 'value'=>10, 'color'=>'black'}=>[Item1, Item3], {'name'=>'test2', 'value'=>10, 'color'=>'blue'}=>[Item2, Item4]}
```

Any other approach will also be helpful.

Comment: So you want to add the `color => red` key value pair to the hashes being used as keys in the shop hash? If that is what you mean then you will have to iterate over the shop hash in some way. How else could you change each key?

Comment: You need to edit to add quotes to keys and values to make them valid Ruby objects. Also, I presume you mean `Item1 = {...`, rather than `Item1{...`. Same elsewhere. What is `Item`, as opposed to `Item1`, `Item2`,...? Lastly, please show your desired output when "`color'` is included. For example, would the key for the first element of `shop` be `{'name'=>'test', 'value'=>10, 'color'=>['black', 'red']}`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Please see edited quedtion with expected output..

Comment: If the color is part of the hash key but not "part of grouping keys", what color do you want to add if the members of one group have different color?

Comment: Why are you using this "template" ? you can simply use "name" as key and other as values in hash. Like this `{"test" => {"value" => 10, "items" => [Item1, Item2]}}`

Comment: Thanks @LukasBaliak But in that case how can i group items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial code is equivalent to

```
shop = items.group_by do | i | 
  {'name' => i['name'], 'value' => i['value'] }
end
```

To add the color to the key hash, simply do

```
shop = items.group_by do | i | 
  {'name' => i['name'], 'value' => i['value'], 'color' => i['color'] }
end
```

Now, you are grouping by color too.

If this is not your intention ("but not as part of grouping key"), i.e. if there can be items with the same name and value but different color, and these items shall go into the same group, then you first have to decide which color should be in the group's hash then.

In that case, postprocessing the hash would be simplest:

```
shop = items.group_by do | i | 
  {'name' => i['name'], 'value' => i['value'] }
end
shop.keys.each { | h | h['color'] = shop[h].sample['color'] }
```